# Wheat for animal consumption safe for human consumption?

Tags: pesticides

A few days ago I got a hand mill since at times I have enough free time to grow grain. Problem is that to test sourdough I got whole wheat grain for animal consumption, it was the only wheat grain available.

I do not know if animal consumption wheat is safe to eat, because of the pesticides, note that I know it is not lethal but I would rather wait and grow wheat myself than be intoxicated

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Sustainable Living.  Can you elaborate on the sustainability angle you are interested in?

Comment: This sounds like it belongs over on cooking.se.

Answer (score 1):

So today I inspected the wheat more closely, I found some animal droppings of what assume were birds from the seller and a dead insect along with some trash. It actually calms me down a little to see those insects and animal droppings, if it is dirty I would just wash it and let it dry.

A couple of notes:

The bran I am going to eat too in different things other than bread, it is two thirds of the entire amount of wheat I bought.

From 2kg of wheat I got 680g of flour, and it does not even look that white. So makes me think how much wheat we waste just because it does not look "white". Even if I have little time to harvest grains in my grandma's home I am going to continue getting the grains myself for milling it at home, or at least try to do it more often because for each kilo of flour I get at the store it means more than two thirds of wheat that was used to make that flour were wasted and given to animals as food, that in turn you guys know contributes to methane because really wheat was farmed for millenia by humans to be consumed by humans. Grazing animals have a different diet.

I may have gone a little too astray from it... But here is my answer; it is safe, just check your wheat and make sure it does not look too clean or too dirty, wash it if you do not know where it came from, and lastly do not waste any of it, the whole grain has nutritional value you would just be wasting food!

Comment: Regarding the colour of flour: store-bought flour is actually bleached white - it's (generally) not the case of companies "wasting" wheat.

Comment: After much research I found out indeed not so much is not packaged, still thanks for the input